# How to trap on exit 1 only in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-trap

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash


function hello {
    echo "Hello World!"
}

trap hello EXIT
```

The problem is that this function will execute on any exit code for that script. if I append an `exit 1` at the end of the script, `Hello World!` will be printed, but it also will get printed on exit 0.

Is there a way to run a function within a script, but only if the script exits with exit code 1 only? (actually anything other than 0 works too.)

Comment: Here is a hint, replace `Hello World!` with `$?` and see what it prints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, but with losing the exit code in the function:

```
trap '[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && hello' EXIT
```

If you need the exit code in the function, you have to do the test inside the function.

Answer (score 5):

Capture the current status in the function:

```sh
bye() {
  local status=$?
  (( status == 1 )) && echo "Hello World!"
  echo "Exiting with status $status"
  exit $status
}
trap bye EXIT
# ...
exit $some_status
```